# Custom operator form for system functions?

Tags: functions, core-language, operators

There are some functions for which an operator form would make sense but isn't implemented. For example, I'd like to make this work:

```
RandomSample[3] @ Range[10]
```

You can do something like this:

```
Unprotect[RandomSample]; Off[RandomSample::lrwl]
RandomSample[n_][x_] := RandomSample[x, n]
```

But I wonder if there is a standard technique to define operator forms for system functions?

Comment: I take it you would not find `RandomSample[#, 3] &[Range[10]]` to be satisfying.  In any case, a very good question.

Comment: How about `Infix` notation? It looks nice for your example: `Range[10]~RandomSample~3`. No need to `Unprotect` anything.

Comment: You can find more function run `EntityList[EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol","Curryable"]]`

Comment: @yode that's a nice feature!

Comment: The answer to this question is NO. There is no standard way of defining operator forms of a built-in function short of `Unprotect`ing and defining one yourself or hoping that in a future release Wolfram Inc. would include one.

Comment: @Jens, infix works in that case but not with more general pipelines, eg using `RightComposition`

Comment: @RunnyKine, can you clarify what you mean by "no standard way" - are there non-standard ways, eg via pattern manipulation?

Comment: @alancalvitti To be fair, he did *not* explicitly ask for a method that works for *all* system functions. The only standard technique that could work without exceptions is to define your own named function, but that's trivial.

Answer (score 7):

A true operator would use SubValues but here's a position-coded pseudo-operator form "constructor" using UpValues that can be applied to most or all system functions:

```
\[Bullet] /: h_[pre___, \[Bullet], post___] := 
  Function[expr, h[pre, expr, post]];
```

For example,

```
Dataset[{a, b, d, c}][
  Partition[\[Bullet], 2] /*  
   MapIndexed[Rule, \[Bullet], {2}]] // Normal
```

> {{a->{1,1},b->{1,2}},{d->{2,1},c->{2,2}}}

• Could not use SubValues with this definition - too deep for evaluator.

• Position coding enables options or other parameters (only Map and a few other system functions allow this). This is also useful for functions like MemberQ where one might operate on either the first or second slot.

• It uses Bullet because it looks nice and takes only 2 chars to input: Alt-8 (ideally, one should be able to type two commas in a row to represent the desired slot, but overloading Null doesn't work).

• Though it seems it only saves one character compared to #...& Function syntax, it also avoids parentheses when combined with RightComposition as in the above example: ... /* (MapIndexed[Rule,#, {2}]&).

Comment: Very nice! A possible slight improvement: `\[Bullet] /: h_[pre___, \[Bullet], post___] := Function[, h[pre, ##, post], {HoldAll}]` This allows you to splice in arbitrarily many arguments and also `Hold`s them so that the `Hold` related attributes of `f` can kick in (however, both these "features" are not supported for the built-in operator forms, so this might confuse the user)

Answer (score 6):

Since there was no objection to my comment, I'll post it as an answer:

By using [`Infix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Infix.html) notation, an operators with arbitrarily many arguments (more than one) can be written as in this example:

```
Range[10]~RandomSample~3
```

So the operator separates the arguments in the input.

If, on the other hand, you want to actually use a re-defined version of the built-in operator in your programming, then the answer would be different. A custom operator for a system function can always be defined as below:

```
randomSample[n_] := Function[list, RandomSample[list, n]]

rs = randomSample[3]

(* ==> Function[list$, RandomSample[list$, 3]] *)

rs[Range[10]]

(* ==> {6, 2, 3} *)

randomSample[3][Range[10]]

(* ==> {8, 2, 10} *)
```