# An argument which returns the function that is applied to this argument

Tags: functions, arguments

Is it possible to construct an argument such that any function applied to this argument returns itself, i.e. (the slot is used to allow for additional arguments in the function)

```
x = getfunc;
anyfunction[x]
(* Out: anyfunction[#]& *)
```

More specifically, I like to use an existing function in various places of the argument without changing the function. E.g. if `x` is a list, I want any function which is applied to `x` to be mapped on `x` **without** changing the function by using `Map`, i.e. something like

```
x = {getfunc@a, getfunc@b}
anyfunction[x]
(* Out: {anyfunction[#]&[a],anyfunction[#]&[b]} *)
```

Comment: This is a very weird request, and seems to be a very clear example of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/346882).

Comment: While I agree with @AccidentalFourierTransform, if you *really* want to achieve something like this, [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135342/36508) should give you a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks @Mathe172, with `getfunc /: anyfunc_[getfunc[x_]] := anyfunc[#] &` I can solve the problem: `anyfunc[getfunc[x]]` returns `anyfunc[#]&`. Modifying the right-hand side can then solve all other related problems like my example with `Map`.

Comment: "the slot is used to allow for additional arguments in the function" - either I didn't get it or it is exactly the opposite. Slot makes it a one argument function, `##` would allow additional arguments, just like `anyfunction` alone.

Comment: @Kuba sorry, I was a bit sloppy. What I meant was the possibility `getfunc /: anyfunc_[getfunc[x_], opt___] := anyfunc[#, opt] &` which is a trivial extension.

Comment: @MarcoB I found the solution to my question by use of that thread, although it seems to be a different topic. If the policy is to mark it as duplicate anyways, I can confirm it.

Comment: @Passi It is really up to you. You can accept the suggestion, which will close the question and mark it as duplicate. A few people have also agreed to the possible duplication through the review process. If a few more do, the question will also be closed as a duplicate. **Closing does not reflect poorly on the question** at all. It is just housekeeping: it links your question with the previous one and indicates that yours has an answer elsewhere. It therefore increases the chances that others with the same problem will find either one of the two linked questions and arrive at a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the explantions.